# Why is Jest setting "transformIgnorePatterns" causing issue with scoped CSS import in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm having an import problem with the Jest testing of my React app after I added `transformIgnorePatterns` to the Jest settings. I have added just the default settings below in the "jest" section of the root package.json file:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "/node_modules/",
  "\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$"
]
```

This has caused an issue with a scoped CSS import that I have in app.js.

`import '@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css';`

```
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){@charset "UTF-8";
                                                                                             ^

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      1 | import AppRoutes from './routes/appRoutes';
      2 | import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
    > 3 | import '@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css';
        | ^
      4 |
      5 | // local imports
      6 | import './App.css';

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.js:3:1)
```

If I comment out that CSS import line the problem goes away. What is causing this issue and how do I fix it?

I'm going to need babel to compile an uncompiled node_module for Jest to run without error ultimately, but am trying to solve this issue first.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem too with my CRA-based app. Even though your `transformIgnorePatterns` rules match the CSS file you're importing (assuming the file exists under `/node_modules/`), either Jest is not ignoring it properly or some other configuration is trying to handle the CSS file as a Javascript file.

While I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong to surface this, here is my workaround:  Add another configuration option to package.json's "jest" object,

```
"jest": {
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    /* whatever patterns you already had */
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  }
},
```

`moduleNameMapper` allows you to stub out resources — in this case all modules that end with `.css, .less, .sass, or .scss` — replacing them with [the `identity-obj-proxy` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/identity-obj-proxy). This prevents Jest from trying to parse these files as actual CSS code.